# Ошибка импорта модуля в Python

Tags: python, vds, venv

На винде работает в PyCharm, а на VDS не работает..
Структура:

- FOLDER_PROJECT

  - VENV
  - APP_FOLDER

    - wsgi.py
    - __ init__.py (без пробела, просто по другому не отображает нижнее подчеркивание)

Содержимое wsgi.py:

```
from APP_FOLDER import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=False)
```

Активирую виртуальное окружение:

```
source VENV/bin/activate
```

Пытаюсь протестировать приложение:

```
python -m wsgi.py
```

В итоге ошибка:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'APP_FOLDER'

При активном виртуальном окружении:

```
python --version # Python 3.9.16
```

На винде Python 3.9

Comment: А версии питона одинаковые?

Comment: да. на VDS и на Винде стоит 3.9

Comment: Странно вы как то импорт делаете.

Comment: python --version # Python 3.9.16 где была запущена эта команда? на сервере?

Comment: @Александр, да - на сервере. Что странного в импорте?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь импортировать из пакета уровнем выше, хотя импорт должен быть только из каталогов уровнем ниже, вот это и странно.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/

ошибка из какого места вы импортируете.
где ваша папка.
Поэкпериментируйте
./APP_FOLDER
FOLDER_PROJECT/APP_FOLDER
и так далее
пока не найдёте правильный ответ
Что он считает корневым каталогом, от этого и плясать
Удачи